# Substract the value of the previous column for each columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume that I have a DataFrame that looks like this

```
    A B  C
1   0 4  7
2   3 8  10
3   5 13 19
```

and I want to substract the values of column B by those of column A, and the values of column C by those of column B which would output:

```
    A B C
1   0 4 3
2   3 5 2
3   5 8 6
```

what's the easiest way to perform such an operation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diff`:

```
df.diff(axis=1).fillna(df)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
1  0.0  4.0  3.0
2  3.0  5.0  2.0
3  5.0  8.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

With matrix multiplication in plain numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

M = np.array([[0, 4,  7],
             [3, 8,  10],
             [5, 13, 19]])

X = np.array([[0, -1,  0],
             [0, 0,  -1],
             [0, 0, 0]])

M + M @ X
# Output : array([[0, 4, 3],
#                 [3, 5, 2],
#                 [5, 8, 6]])
```

or with pandas

```
# also works with panda data frames
df = pd.DataFrame(M)
df
df + df.dot(X)
```